can't enter /dashboard commit, after login
When logging in, 2 messages appear on the console at the same time
I have filled in the login form, and a success message appears in the console but the must login message also appears at the same time
and I still can't enter /dashboard
//message in console
login success
PrivateRoute.jsx:6 Must Login
PrivateRoute.jsx:6 Must Login

//Routes.jsx

import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import LoginPage from './pages/Login/LoginPage';
import DashboardPage from './pages/Dashboard/DashboardPage';
import PrivateRoute from './components/PrivateRoute';

const MyRoutes = ({ loggedIn, setLoggedIn }) => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Fragment>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/login" element={<LoginPage setLoggedIn={setLoggedIn} />} />
        <Route exact path='/' element={<PrivateRoute/>}>
        <Route
          exact
          path="/dashboard"
          loggedIn={loggedIn}
          element={<DashboardPage />}
        />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/login" />} />
      </Routes>
      </Fragment>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default MyRoutes;

//PrivateRoute.jsx


import React from 'react';
import { Route, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const PrivateRoute = ({ element: Component, loggedIn, ...rest }) => {
  if (!loggedIn) {
    console.log('Must Login');
    return <Navigate to="/login" />;
  }

  const userVerified = true;

  if (!userVerified) {
    console.log('User has not been verified.');
    return <Navigate to="/" />;
  }

  
  return <Route {...rest} element={<Component />} />;
};

export default PrivateRoute;

//Login.jsx

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const Login = ({ setLoggedIn }) => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [loginSuccess, setLoginSuccess] = useState(false);

  const handleLogin = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post('localhost', {
        username,
        password,
      });
      // console.log(response.data);
      console.log('login success')
      localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
      setLoggedIn(true);
      setLoginSuccess(true);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  if (loginSuccess) {
    return <Navigate to="/dashboard" />;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={username}
        onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Username"
      />
      <input
        type="password"
        value={password}
        onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Password"
      />
      <button onClick={handleLogin}>Login</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;

// App.js

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import AppRoutes from './Routes';

function App() {
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AppRoutes loggedIn={loggedIn} setLoggedIn={setLoggedIn} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

I want to be allowed to enter /dashboard if I am logged in, in this situation i cant enter /dashboard
